# Can I play LOTRO on Nvidia ION based netbook running 64bit linux?

Tags: linux, lord-of-the-rings-online, wine

I have a ASUS Eee PC 1215N netbook, from the Seashell series.
It has a Nvidia ION graphic processor.
I'm running 64bit Ubuntu Linux (11.10 Oneiric Ocelot) on it.

I've tried to install LOTRO on it following the HOWTO on

But the game fails to run with one of:

- Game Error [105], "Could not initialize Direct3D. Please ensure that
  DirectX 9.0c [Dec 2005] or higher is installed."
- Game Error [129], "Hardware texture compression support was not detected. This video card feature is required to run the game."

The PyLotro wine output contains eiter

> err:wgl:has_opengl Failed to load libGL: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
>   err:wgl:has_opengl OpenGL support is disabled.
>
> err:d3d_caps:WineD3D_CreateFakeGLContext Can't find a suitable iPixelFormat.
>
> err:d3d:InitAdapters Failed to get a gl context for default adapter
>
> Direct3D9 is not available without OpenGL.

Or a repeating errors ending in

> ERROR: ld.so: object 'libdlfaker.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded: ignored.
>
> ERROR: ld.so: object 'librrfaker.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded: ignored.
>
> Xlib:  extension "NV-GLX" missing on display ":2".
>   Xlib:  extension "NV-GLX" missing on display ":2".
>
> err:winediag:X11DRV_WineGL_InitOpenglInfo Direct rendering is disabled, most likely your OpenGL drivers haven't been installed correctly

Comment: I think that Codemaster's support can help you more than we, you should try to post on their forum aswell, if you haven't done that already.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I've made this question to answer it myself with information I've gathered from the several fora out there.  On Mac OS Leopard, I ended up using Crossover Games. I'll probably buy a licence for that; they contribute a lot back to the wine-project as well.

Comment: And you probably mean [Code*Weavers*](http://www.codeweavers.com/products/cxgames/) not Code*masters*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running software using the ION processor will require extra software. Windows 7 Nvidia supplies [Optimus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nvidia_Optimus). On linux there's a project called [Bumblebee](https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee#readme).

To recap the several sources on the web for 64bit Oneiric:

Install LOTRO roughly following the [howto](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=23486)

```
sudo apt-get install wine winetricks
export WINEPREFIX=$HOME/.wine-lotro
winetricks vcrun2008
winetricks d3dx9
cd /wherever/you've/downloaded/the/game
wine LOTROSetup.exe
```

This will have created a wine environment (sometime revered to as 'bottle') in .wine-lotro in your home directory and installed the game there, including some native windows dll's that the game needs.

To launch the game from wine you'll need the special launcher called [PyLotro](http://www.lotrolinux.com/download.php). Normally on Ubuntu you do

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ajackson-bcs/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pylotro
```

But there's no Oneiric version in the ppa yet. So just get the *source* version (*not* the 'Stand-alone Version' exe one).

To have it use the Nvidia processor, you install [Bumblebee](https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee#readme)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bumblebee
```

And since wine is 32-bit, and 64-bit Oneiric uses multiarch, you install the 32-bit version of some libraries like this

```
sudo apt-get install virtualgl-libs:i386
```

without it you'll see those `LD_PRELOAD` errors.

To have the pylotro launcher use `optirun` to run `wine`, I made a tiny wrapper script like this

```
mkdir $HOME/bin
cat << EOF > $HOME/bin/optiwine
#! /bin/sh
optirun wine \$@
EOF
chmod +x $HOME/bin/optiwine
```

In pylotro  /Tools/Options, tick the Advanced Options and set `/home/{username}/bin/optiwine` as the `Wine Program`. And of course set the right `WINEPREFIX` et al.

Comment: I have followed your instruction and I am able to use pylotro with your wrapper, but I still get the "Hardware texture compression support was not detected." error. Did I miss something? Is there anything you can help me to fix this issue. I will also check the codeweaver forum to see if I can find anything there.

Comment: Very hard to say from what you tell. Is there any difference in the wine output when you run the game with the wrapper instead of wine?